# How does WorkingPrecision in NDSolve handle MachinePrecision?

Tags: machine-precision, precision-and-accuracy

I'm wondering why the following code

```
NDSolve[{y''[t] + y[t] == 0, y[0] == 1., y'[0] == 0}, y, {t, 0, 10}, 
WorkingPrecision -> 6]
```

throws the error/warning, that the precision of the ode (i.e. `MachinePrecision`) is less than `WorkingPrecision`, while

```
NDSolve[{y''[t] + y[t] == 0, y[0] == N[1, 6], y'[0] == 0}, y, {t, 0, 10}, 
WorkingPrecision -> 6]
```

doesn't, although 6 is smaller than `MachinePrecision`. Is there a good reason for this behaviour?

Comment: `MachinePrecision` is a separate type of precision than “arbitrary precision” (for which search the docs, if necessary). Some solvers treat MP as below arbitrary precision no matter what. The main difference is that arbitrary precision tracks an uncertainty bound.  When the bound exceeds the point estimate for the number, the number is treated as equal to zero (within a certain uncertainty). I’m pretty sure in all solvers set the precision of the code passed to them to `WorkingPrecision`, and the message is just a warning. Some solvers DON’T check that the code actually computes in WP.

Comment: The reason for the warning (imo) is that the input represents one desire of the user and the `WorkingPrecision` represent a different one: MP = fast, native FP; no error tracking.  WP -> 6 = slower, software FP; but with error tracking.

Comment: From [`doc`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Precision.html) "MachinePrecision is considered smaller than any explicit precision." Whereas, `N[1, 6]` is an arbitrary-precision number with precision of `6`.